# MySQL Join two tables with condition

Tags: mysql, database

Based on these two tables:

`products`

```
|   ID          |   Active  |   Name        |   No
--------------------------------------------------
|   1           |   1       |   Shirt       |   100
|   2           |   0       |   Pullover    |   200
```

`variants`

```
|   MasterID    |   Active  |   Name    |   No
--------------------------------------------------
|   1           |   1       |   Red     |   101
|   1           |   0       |   Yellow  |   102
```

I want to get every product which is active and also their active variants in one sql.
Relation between those tables `MasterID` -> `ID`

Needed result:

```
ID (master) |   Name    |   No
--------------------------------------------------
1           |   Shirt   |   100
1           |   Red     |   101
```

I tried it with using union, but then I am not able to get the belonging MasterIDs.

Comment: A side question, why are ids same for multiple products? An id should be unique as per my knowledge.

Comment: @PrerakSola  just want to ask that, are Id and MasterId relationoship between this two table?

Comment: Updatetd the question, thank you guys.

Comment: Is it a problem if I ask you to create [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need a simple join:

```
select *
from products
left join variants
    on products.ID = variants.MasterID
where products.Active = 1
and variants.Active = 1
```

**Update** after requirements were made clearer:

```
select ID, Name, No, 'products' as RowType
from products
where Active = 1
union
select variants.MasterID as ID, variants.Name, variants.No, 'variants' as RowType
from products
join variants
    on products.ID = variants.MasterID
where products.Active = 1
and variants.Active = 1
order by ID, RowType, No
```

I've assumed you want the results ordered by ID, with `products` followed by `variants`.  The No column may order it this way implicitly (it's impossible to know without real data), in which case the `RowType` column can be removed.  The `order by` clause might need to be altered to match your specific RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

This should gives you the expected result:

```
select * from products left join variants on products.id = variants.masterId 
where products.active=1 and variants.active=1
```

If not please add the expected result to your question.

Comment: Added the expected result... `select * ` returns the cols for every product as well if it is a variant.